# check if checkboxes in GridView are ticked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have three checkboxes in a GridView but the user can only select one checkbox. So if they select the first checkbox, I need to alert them them that they cannot select the other two.

```
        <asp:GridView CssClass="tblResults" runat="server" ID="dgDetails" 
              OnRowDataBound="dgDetails_ItemDataBound" 
              DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
             AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
             <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                <Columns> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApproved1" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApproved2" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved3">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApproved3" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                  </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
protected void dgDetails_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;
            Quote.QuoteDetails qd = e.Row.DataItem as Quote.QuoteDetails;

            CheckBox chkApproved1 = e.Row.FindControl("chkApproved1") as CheckBox;
            CheckBox chkApproved2 = e.Row.FindControl("chkApproved2") as CheckBox;
            CheckBox chkApproved3 = e.Row.FindControl("chkApproved3") as CheckBox;
       }
    }
```

I tried using something like this in query:

```
$('#<%= chkApproved1.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {

                    }  
            });
```

But that causes the error:The name 'chkApproved1' does not exist in the current context.

So how can I check if the checkboxes in the GridView have been ticked?

Comment: Only public page members are accessible within <%=...%> tokens.  Change the checkbox control modifier to public and it should work.

Comment: apply a class to checkboxes and selected them by class - the id can not be found because is dynamically created by gridview and not preexist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to give alert if first checkbox is checked use the below script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {       

        $("table[id$='dgDetails']").find("input[id*='chkApproved1']").change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        alert('Hi');
                    }
                });
     });
```

Here is the code that will help you to prevent other checkbox to check if first is checked.

```
              if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                    
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved1") != -1) { var1 = 1 }
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved2") != -1) { var2 = 1 }
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved3") != -1) { var3 = 1 }
                    if (var1 == 1 && var2 == 1 && var3 == 1) {
                        var2 = 0; var3 = 0;
                        $("table[id$='dgDetails']").find("input[id*='chkApproved2']").attr("checked", false);
                        $("table[id$='dgDetails']").find("input[id*='chkApproved3']").attr("checked", false);
                    }
                    else if (var1 == 1 && var2 == 1) {
                        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved1") != -1) { var1 = 0 }
                        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved2") != -1) { var2 = 0 }
                        alert('You can\'t select this checkbox2');
                        $(this).attr("checked", false);
                    }
                    else if (var1 == 1 && var3 == 1) {
                        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved1") != -1) { var1 = 0 }
                        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved3") != -1) { var3 = 0 }
                        alert('You can\'t select this checkbox3');
                        $(this).attr("checked", false);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved1") != -1) { var1 = 0 }
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved2") != -1) { var2 = 0 }
                    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved3") != -1) { var3 = 0 }
                }
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for the help. But how would I also see if they try to check the second checkbox but the first one is already checked? They can only check one at a time

Comment: @user123456789 just try to change this `.find("input[id*='chkApproved1']")` to this `.find("input[id*='chkApproved']")` and let me know if this works.

Comment: you can use some variable like `var1=0, var2=0, var3=0` after check make the corresponding value to `1` then you can compare all three. i.e `if($(this).attr("id").indexOf("chkApproved1")!=-1){var1=1}`

Comment: Making that change now works for all the checkboxes. The alert gets called for any checkbox I tick. So how do I check if the checkbox was ticked?

Comment: @user123456789 see my comment just above your comment write that code inside `if ($(this).is(":checked")) {       }` for all three checkbox. var1=1 means it is checked, 0 means not checked.

Comment: ok thanks I understand. One last thing - I want to stop the user from ticking more than one checkbox. If if the first one is ticked and they try tick the second checkbox, how do I make the second checkbox unchecked?